# Mongoimport error with malformed CSV file

Tags: mongoimport

While importing a csv file to mongodb , a field having two new lines in it. When I am importing it , it is giving an error showing "csv file ends while inside quoted fields". can anyone help me how to sort this problem

Comment: could you add your full import command?

Comment: What exactly did your CSV file look like?